# How to fill an array by row in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia

I would like to fill an Array object by row in the Julia language. 
The `reshape` function wants to fill by column (Julia is column major).

```
julia> reshape(1:15, 3,5)
3x5 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  4  7  10  13
 2  5  8  11  14
 3  6  9  12  15
```

Is there a way to persuade it to fill by row? It feels like there should be an obvious answer, but I've not found one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One suggestion:

```
julia> reshape(1:15, 5, 3) |> transpose
3x5 Array{Int64,2}:
  1   2   3   4   5
  6   7   8   9  10
 11  12  13  14  15
```

Comment: thanks, does `|>` have a name so I can Google more about it?

Comment: pipe? function composition? [docs](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/base/?highlight=%7C%3E#Base.|>)

Comment: `reshape(1:15, 5, 3) |> transpose` is just another way to write `transpose(reshape(1:15, 5, 3))`

Answer (score 5):

With array comprehension:

```
julia> [i+5*j for j=0:2,i=1:5]
3x5 Array{Int64,2}:
  1   2   3   4   5
  6   7   8   9  10
  11  12  13  14  15
```

Ah, it's just more than 10x times faster than other suggestion (actually, an embarrassing 100x on my initial benchmark).

Comment: how can this approach be modified when the elements are in an `Array`, say `A = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.]`? (the different types are for emphasis only, not to slow things down)

Comment: never mind, just have to apply it to the indices of `A`: `[A[i + 5 * j] for j = 0:2, i = 1:5]`. It's the little tricks...

Comment: beat me to it... was about to write this!

Comment: but my general impression was that comprehensions were slow

Comment: actually, they are usually fast, and moreover, require less allocations (the `transpose` does a copy).

Answer (score 2):

[`permutedims`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/arrays/?highlight=reshape#Base.permutedims) is another choice when dealing with more general multi-way arrays.

```
julia> permutedims(reshape(1:24, 2,3,4), [2,1,3])
3x2x4 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  2
 3  4
 5  6

[:, :, 2] =
  7   8
  9  10
 11  12

[:, :, 3] =
 13  14
 15  16
 17  18

[:, :, 4] =
 19  20
 21  22
 23  24
```

however, it's slowest among other suggestions in your specific case.